# REST API unable to copy document when file name is long

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm using `SharePoint designer 2013` workflow REST API to copy documents from one library to another.

Its working fine. Please check below URL

```
 https://Company.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/_api/web/folders/getbyurl('Inbox')/files/getbyurl('Test1.pdf')/copyTo(strNewUrl='/sites/Demo/Preparation/VMA120/Test1.pdf',bOverWrite=true)
```

but it can not copy file when file name's length is more than 32 character

e.g. : **AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.pdf**

```
https://Company.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/_api/web/folders/getbyurl('Inbox')/files/getbyurl('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.pdf')/copyTo(strNewUrl='/sites/Demo/Preparation/VMA120/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.pdf',bOverWrite=true)
```

Please help me here.

In above URL file with name **AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.pdf**   having length more than 32 char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitations In this section apply to the total length of the URL path to a folder or a file in SharePoint Server 2010 but not to the length of any parameters. Also, these limitations apply only to un-encoded URLs, not to encoded URLs. There is no limit to encoded URLs in SharePoint Server 2010. The limitations are the following:  [Check this Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919564(v=office.14).aspx)

`The total URL length limit is 256 characters - SharePoint won't allow you to upload a file or folder if the total URL length exceeds that.`

**260 Unicode (UTF-16) code units** – the characters in a full file path, not including a domain/server name.
**256 Unicode (UTF-16) code units** – the characters in a full folder path, not including the file name and the domain/server name.
**128 Unicode (UTF-16) code units** - characters in a path component, that is, a file or folder name.
**260 Unicode (UTF-16) code units** – the characters in a full path, including a domain/server name for use with Office clients.
**256 Unicode (UTF-16) code units** – the characters in a full path including the domain/server name, for use with Active X controls.